# C#'s 'lock' in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I want to lock something in C#, i do

```
private readonly object _listManagerLock = new object();

lock (_listManagerLock)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("startin determening");
          AssignArray(log._algorithm);
          Console.WriteLine("ending determening");
      }
```

Perfectly threadsafe, nothing can go wrong. Is there a way to implement this into C++?

Comment: Maybe:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard ?

Comment: What exactly is this code locking? You seem to create a random object and lock it, then do something that has nothing to do with that object. Is `object` supposed to just be a mutex?

Comment: @NicolBolas In C#, you can lock any `object`. Yeah, it's weird, but in C++ you can `throw` an `int`, so...

Comment: @NikosC.: OK, but what does that *mean*? Does that object get its own mutex? Does every locked object share a global mutex?

Comment: @NicolBolas The object itself is treated like a mutex. If you lock an `object` instance, you acquire a lock on it. I assume this design decision was made so that people can easily lock the objects they need to synchronize access to without knowing what a mutex actually is or having to define a separate "lock" object. If this was the case for C++ too, then imagine having an `std::vector<int> vec` member, and then just doing `vec.lock()` before accessing it. It's convenient, and C# focuses on convenience. If you're asking though how this is implemented under the hood, I don't actually know :-)

Comment: @NicolBolas There are 2 threads that access a list in a method in this function, to suspend one and let the other one do it, you can just lock it. That way it only lets one thread do stuff

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ does not have an equivalent to the `lock` keyword. You need to create an `std::mutex` instance instead, and lock that:

```
private:
    std::mutex _listManagerLock;

// ...
```

You could lock and unlock it manually:

```
_listManagerLock.lock();
// ...
_listManagerLock.unlock();
```

But that's not recommended, because this can leave the mutex locked in certain circumstances, like when an exception is thrown, or when you simply forgot to `unlock()` it. Instead, you should use an [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard):

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_listManagerLock);
// ...
```

The lock will be released automatically when the current scope is exited. To force a scope, and get something equivalent to your C# code, you would do:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_listManagerLock);
    // ...
}
```